# google map error TypeError: h[b] is undefined

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to simply test the geolocation example, my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/map/jquery.ui.map.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/map/jquery.ui.map.overlays.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#user_location').gmap().bind('init', function(evt, map) {
        $('#user_location').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {
            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                $('#user_location').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition, 'bounds': true});
                $('#user_location').gmap('addShape', 'Circle', { 
                    'strokeWeight': 0, 
                    'fillColor': "#008595", 
                    'fillOpacity': 0.25, 
                    'center': clientPosition, 
                    'radius': 15, 
                    'clickable': false 
                });
            }
        });   
    });
});
</script>
```

But when I try to run this, I get `TypeError: h[b] is undefined`

Also on a sidenote, is it possible to store a reference to this marker so that I can display message, or remove it later?

Comment: That code is not complete (at least I can't easily make a local version work).  Can you make a jsfiddle that exhibits the error?

Comment: have the same problem, have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you come across the same problem, try to:

1. replace minified version of map plugin to full (it could help you understand the problem)
2. make sure you have linked all the neccessary javascript files

In my case, I have missed to link this two libraries (just compare to what libraries are linked in the example file):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.ui.map.overlays.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js"></script>
```